# best way of minimising disruption to a website following major changes

Tags: apache-2.2, maintenance, redirection

I was wondering what the best way of minimising disruption to a website caused when major changes may introduce bugs.

For example, does anyone do this:

/site_files_1/...current build...
/site_files_2/...new build...

where the site root is redirected to the site_files_1 directory, than after uploading new versions of files to the site_files_2 directory, and testing, the site root is now redirected to this direcotry. So if major problems arise which were missed during the testing phase, the site root can be redirected back to the site_files_1 directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change the apache host config file and restart apache maybe? Or is the site smart enough to find out itself that it's broken?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Load Balanced site with multiple nodes each individually capable of supporting your full capacity one way to do this is to upgrade a single node at a time. Once you have upgraded the first node you can place it into production and hold for a specified period of time before upgrading other nodes. In the event of a bug or other issue you can simply roll back. This solution is not possible for all applications/and configurations however load balancers can make fail over between nodes much, much easier.